# If one isn't going to fast on Yom Kippur, should one make Kiddush?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, kiddush

Let's say there's a household where the husband and wife are both sick such that they need to eat and drink on Yom Kippur.

If the entire household knows they won't be fasting, for very valid reasons, should they make kiddush to sanctify the holiness of the day?